# How is inheritance implemented in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, implementation

How exactly is inheritance implemented in Java? For example, consider this:

```
class A {
    public void foo() {
         System.out.print("A");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    ...
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B test = new B();
        test.foo(); // how is foo() called?
}
```

Below the line, would the compiler just dump the definition of A.foo() into the body of class B? Like

```
class B extends A {
    ...
    public void foo() {
         System.out.print("A");
    }
}
```

Or is foo somehow looked up in class A and called there?

Comment: `B.foo()` wouldn't compile in the first place, because it's not a static method. Did you mean `test.foo()`? (But no, the compiler doesn't copy method implementations...)

Comment: B.foo();  does not compile at all.

Comment: Oops. I meant test.foo(); check the updated version.

Comment: @Jon: How would the call to foo() look like below the line, then?

Comment: When do you mean by "below the line"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method bodies aren't copied in the undefined method body of a subclass. Instead, when you call

```
B test = new B();
test.foo();
```

It will look trough its hierarchy, going up a level every time it can't find an implementation.
First it will check `B` which has no implementation. One level above that there's `A` which does, so it will use that one.

Comment: At least notionally. I'd expect that the VM would build a lookup table once per type to make this rather more efficient, but the effect is the same.

Comment: I think inheritance is implemented by using the design pattern Chain of responsibility, when the compiler find a redefinition, it puts the code of the method in the class, when it doens't find redefinition, it generates a method which delegates to the base class equivalent to super.foo();

Answer (score 4):

This may be able to assist you, explanation from the book Ivor Horton's Begining Java 7

> I said at the beginning of this chapter that a derived class extends a base class. This is not just jargon — it
>   really does do this. As I have said several times, inheritance is about what members of the base class are
>   accessible in a derived class, not what members of the base class exist in a derived class object. An object of
>   a subclass contains all the members of the original base class, plus any new members that you have defi ned
>   in the derived class. This is illustrated in Figure 6-3.

[image]