# Are methods copied when objects are created?

Tags: java, methods

When a object is created, Java creates a copy of the attributes of the class, but, what happens, in memory, with the methods? Does Java create a copy of the code of these or creates only one copy of these for all the objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is inheritance implemented in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241499/how-is-inheritance-implemented-in-java)

Comment: @cybersam Your "duplicate" is about inheritance, the question about instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

They're not. Because Java is statically typed, an object looks something like this in the VM:

```
class_id,
field0,
field1,
...
```

The code of the method to call can then be associated with the class, not the object, so no duplication is needed. I'm guessing you're coming from a language like Python or Javascript where you can reassign methods on instances? In Java, you tend to do this with decorators, instead.

Comment: But what if the method gets changed after instantiation?

Comment: Some JVMs let you do hot code replacement, but that's an edge case. Method bodies practically never change before or after instantiation.

Comment: @ACV That's not really a thing that can happen?

Comment: @ACV it doesn't change. Ever.And when it does through some meta-JVM-hack, it is again the same method for all instances of the class.

Comment: @Ingo [hot code replacement](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F). It's surprised me when using a remote debugger.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html , but it only adds something, not really modifies.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann that doesn't change the principle that all instances of the same class share the same set of methods, so no need to copy them.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann It still doesn't create different "method versions" for one class. You always end up with one method that all instances of a class share.

Comment: My point was just that a method implementation can be changed after instantiation, but yes, it'll change for all objects of that class and classloader.